# Popular level article on monster group

Tags: gr.group-theory, popularization, reference-request

People who are not mathematicians (or high school students who are in maths) often become interested in what is the Monster Group - mainly because of unusual name. Since it's not my field, I'm able only to give short description - and sometimes that's not. So I'm interested in finding some article (or book) which can be used as reference for further reading. Obviously, it would better if this article could be found somewhere online for free.

Comment: In fact, there's a whole book! http://www.amazon.com/Symmetry-Monster-Greatest-Quests-Mathematics/dp/0192807226

Comment: Are you looking for a reference for you or for your friends?  Terry Gannon's book "Moonshine beyond the Monster" would be a good introduction for mathematicians.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group 

Comment: http://www.ams.org/notices/200209/what-is.pdf ? 